# Agilent 66332A DC Source RS232 Ubuntu 12.04 SCPI

Tags: serial-port, ubuntu-12.04, drivers

I have an Agilent 66332A DC Source, and I want to program it so that I can set the current, voltage, and output on/off. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit so the drivers don't work. I've contacted Agilent support, and they gave me nothing. I know that the DC source uses SCPI. Is there some way that I can talk to the DC source using the terminal and send SCPI commands? I've tried minicom, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm using a RS232 connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be manual for this DC source so read SCPI commands from there.

I assume that minicom sends line-feed character after each `enter` you press, but SCPI requires `\n` for command separator. Hence the Minicom does not work.

However you can just echo commands to serial port from bash command line.

1. Setup serial port

   `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 raw speed 9600 -cstopb cs8 -ixon`
2. Echo commands to /dev/ttyS0

   `echo -en '*RST\n' > /dev/ttyS0`

Notice: I'm assuming your device is connected to `/dev/ttyS0`.